# "start ecs" does not work on arm64 based instance a1.large

Tags: amazon-ecs, arm64

I am in the process of migrating our containers from m5.large instances to a1.large instances in our production ecs cluster.

But on this type of instance, when the user data script tries the start ecs command, I noticed it is not available anymore:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-1-90 ~]$ start ecs
-bash: start: command not found
```

I am using the lattest recommended AMI (ami-0c812cd5f7b956092):

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/arm64/recommended
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using the older "Amazon Linux AMI" ECS AMI on your m5 nodes. ARM instances are only supported in Amazon Linux 2 which uses systemd.

For any Amazon Linux 2 based AMI (arm or x86), you'll want to run `systemctl start ecs` instead. Also, for compatibility reasons, you can use the `service` style invocation on either Amazon Linux AMI or Amazon Linux 2: `service ecs start`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I use the subscription topic provided by aws to get the newest ami available:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS-AMI-SubscribeTopic.html

it indeed gives the newest AMI for Amazon Linux AMI
Is there an equivalent for receiving updates about Amazon Linux 2 AMI ?

Comment: When I tried `service start ecs` command, I get:

`
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 9: system: command not found
`

when I tried `systemctl start ecs` , the command blocks

Comment: The best source of AMI info is [SSM parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/retrieve-ecs-optimized_AMI.html). There aren't SNS topics for Amazon Linux 2 based ECS AMIs. As far as the errors you're seeing, a vanilla host shouldn't have anything in that directory and I'm not sure why it is being called.